# CakePHP test suite keep showing "Xdebug is not installed"

Tags: php, cakephp

Hi I don't know what is wrong. I've tried to restart apache several time but CakePHP keep telling "Xdebug is not installed".

I already include xdebug.so at the end of php.ini file.

```
zend_extension= /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so
```

and the result still same.

XAMPP 5.6.8
CakePHP 2.6
OSX
[image]

Comment: Does phpinfo() show xdebug as loaded?

Comment: No xdebug found on phpinfo but I'm sure I already include the xdebug.so into php.ini.

Comment: If phpinfo doesn't show xdebug as loaded then it's not. XAMPP has separate php.ini files for CLI and webserver, so make sure you enable it in the correct file.